# Very slow editing/saving of Facelets files in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, performance, jsf, editor, facelets

I'm experiencing very slow work with Facelets files. I've worked with Facelets files in Eclipse before, but it was:

- older Eclipse (version 3.4)
- older xhtml format (from version 1.8, Icefaces)

Yet I'm working with:

- new Eclipse (in IBM RAD)
- new xhtml format (2.0, PrimeFaces)
- Windows 7, 64 bit

So many things could change. It could be Eclipse bug in new version, but also bug in XSD schema (IceFaces had failed XSD schema, AFAIR, which caused no tag hints functioning). But now it's so awfully slow (each save can take a dozen of seconds) that it is making the normal work very hard...

How to get rid of this performance issue? Maybe the xsd validation should be disabled?

Comment: The only slowness in editing Facelets files which I am aware of is caused by JBoss Tools Knowledge Base plugin in Helios/Indigo (which is disableable in IDE properties). You don't seem to be using JBoss Tools, do you?

Comment: I was using PageDesigner and XML editor. Now I have switched to HTML editor and at least editing seems to be faster, but sometimes it is still quite slow when saving. In Eclipse 3.4 it was almost as fast as text editor...